# Extended the user collection with additional fields

Tags: meteor

Hey I want to add a lot of additional fields to the built in Meteor user collection. So far I've tried

```
if Meteor.isServer

  Meteor.startup ->
    Meteor.users.remove({})
    if Meteor.users.find().fetch().length is 0

      console.log('Seeding database.')
      Characters.remove({})
      Duels.remove({})
      Meteor.users.remove({})

      # Accounts
      options = {
        email: 'example1@example.com'
        password: 'wasdf321'
        profile:
          character: {
            name: 'Testname'
            race: 'human'
          }
      }


      user1Id = Accounts.createUser(options)
```

and when I print out the user object in console, the fields has correctly been added, however, when I check the mongo database, the fields are nowhere to be found

Comment: This code works. I think you are somehow looking at the wrong data. If you run `meteor mongo`, and then `db.users.find().count()` you should get `1`. Then if you do `db.users.findOne()` you should see the correct data in the profile.

Comment: That code works, see [example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/NLrpjaoxz8zEujLNf). Open console and see how `user` object looks like.